# libXML relaxed HTML parsing

Tags: iphone, libxml2

I am trying to scrape some content from an HTML page. I'm using libxml2 and htmlReadMemory to get a xmlDocPtr. The HTML is simple, but it has a problem. It's basically the following:

```
<tr><td><tr><td>Some content</td></tr></td></tr>
```

libxml doesn't like the nested tr, tds. It keeps giving me the following error:

```
HTML parser error : Unexpected end tag : td
      </TD>
           ^
HTML parser error : Unexpected end tag : tr
    </TR>
```

I am using the following option: HTML_PARSE_RECOVER.

At this point nothing i do allows libxml to parse the HTML because of this. I can't change the HTML because I have no access to it.

Anyone have any clues how I can get libxml to parse this sort of HTML?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's the exact call you're using to parse? I'd suggest combining these options if you don't want any errors/warnings:

```
HTML_PARSE_RECOVER|HTML_PARSE_NOERROR|HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING
```

Comment: I do this: theDoc = htmlReadMemory([inData bytes], [inData length], NULL, enc, HTML_PARSE_RECOVER | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);

Comment: Does using HTML_PARSE_NOERROR still parse the document even if there are errors in the HTML?

Comment: Actually, i put in HTML_PARSE_NOERROR and now it's working. Thanks for that!

Comment: I believe libxml will still correctly parse the document in most cases, but it probably depends how badly mangled it is.